# Retrieve data from API (ajax call)

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, json

I have received the below instructions for using a certain API:

> ..secretId and secretKey. Following headers must be included in HTTP request from system. Values for above headers will be provided during integration. Messages could have XML or JSON format. Fortmats Accept: application/xml, Accept: application/json,Content-type: application/xml,Content-type: application/json. Request type GET, url+/idClient/123

This is a cross domain API. My code is below:

```
var url = 'http://test.com'
$.ajax({      
      data: {},
      url: url+'/idClient/123',
      type: 'GET',
      crossDomain: true,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType:'json',
      headers: { "secretId" : 'xxx', "secretKey" : 'xxx' },
      success: function(){},
      error: function...
  });
```

The response StatusTxt is error, so I also tried to use beforeSend:

```
beforeSend: function (request)
{
    request.setRequestHeader('secretId', 'xxx');
    request.setRequestHeader('secretKey', 'xxx');
}
```

How can I improve this code?

Comment: Can you tell what exact problem you have with your code?

Comment: Because this's my first time when i connect to api, i dont know this code it's good. I think is not because i have response error.

Comment: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/ try to look at this link, it solved my problem with request to API controller. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424461/Implementing-Consuming-ASP-NET-WEB-API-from-JQuery This article will help you understand better how to do requests to Web Api.